# Ubuntu make mount point for unused partions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

After installing fresh `ubuntu-20.04` and using automatically create partition i have this partitions:

```
Device         Start       End  Sectors     Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048  97656831 97654784    46.6G Linux  filesystem
/dev/sda2   97656832 101656575  3999744     1.9G Linux  swap         <- swap
/dev/sda3   101656576 174866887 73210312    34.9G Linux  filesystem   
/dev/sda4   174868480 175917055  1048576     512M EFI    System       <- /boot/efi
/dev/sda5   175917056 234440703 58523648    27.9G Linux  filesystem   <- /
```

as you can see i have some partition and `sda1` and `sda3` doesn't have mount point. into `/` as `sda5` i have user data such as `Desktop`,`Documents` and etc

all of my files such as projects source in into this partition and it doesn't have enough space on that and  want to use `sda1` or `sda3` as `/home` partition

below output is my `fstab` content:

```
UUID=3bb8ad93-b414-4a1d-a4cf-e13f434fbe45 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=EF4E-B24E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

here `sda1` and `sda5` doesn't have any mount point and my question is how can i use this unused partitions? i want to have to store data and projects into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mount /dev/sda1 (46GB) on /home to be used for existing and future home directories:

1. Logout
2. CTRL-ALT-F1 and login as root.
3. mv /home /home-hold
4. mkdir /home
5. chmod 755 /home
6. echo '/dev/sda1  /home  ext4   defaults  0 0' >> /etc/fstab
7. mount -a
8. rsync -avh --progress /home-hold/ /home
9. Once you check that everything is copied over, you can delete /home-hold.
10. exit
11. CTRL-ALT-F7
12. Login.

Comment: thank you very much